# Menu in toolbar not appearing

Tags: applications, menu

When I open a program like firefox, for example, the toolbar looks like this:
[image]

But when I minimize the windows and reopen it, then the menu 'File, Edit...' etc disappears:[image]

Why does this happen? And how can I make to move it to the left, where there is more space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've installed some kind of third-party software in an attempt to emulate the "global menu" from Unity. I would recommend removing this as it appears to be buggy.